# PHP: Split string

Tags: php, string, split

How do I split a string by `.` delimiter in PHP? For example, if I have the string `"a.b"`, how do I get `"a"`?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

[`explode`](http://php.net/explode) does the job:

```
$parts = explode('.', $string);
```

You can also directly fetch parts of the result into variables:

```
list($part1, $part2) = explode('.', $string);
```

Answer (score 28):

`explode('.', $string)`

If you know your string has a fixed number of components you could use something like

```
list($a, $b) = explode('.', 'object.attribute');
echo $a;
echo $b;
```

Prints:

```
object
attribute
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$string_val = 'a.b';

$parts = explode('.', $string_val);

print_r($parts);
```

Documentation: *[explode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)*

Answer (score 7):

The following will return you the "a" letter:

```
$a = array_shift(explode('.', 'a.b'));
```

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
explode('.', 'a.b');
```

*[explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)*

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = explode('.',$string);
```

Returns an array of split elements.

Answer (score -1):

To explode with '.', use:

```
explode('\\.', 'a.b');
```