# News system with images table

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have 2 tables. One that contains the news and second witch contains the images.

**news table:**

news_id

news_head

news_content

**Gallery table**

gallerynews_id

gallerynews_newsid

gallerynews_filename

My question is how do i join them together (php/mysql) so the images match the news?
For example. 1 news/story can contain 4 images. The result must look something like this:

**News 1(head)**
image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3 (related images for the news).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT N.*, G.*
FROM news N
LEFT JOIN gallery G ON N.news_id = G.gallerynews_newsid
```

I use a left join so that if there are no images, you still get your news item.

---

```
SELECT N.*, GROUP_CONCAT(G.gallerynews_filename)
FROM news N
LEFT JOIN gallery G ON N.news_id=G.gallerynews_newsid
```

Comment: Thanks for yor answer. How do i categorize them in PHP? :-)

Comment: Categorize them? Is this for a list page, or the news article page?

Comment: Its for a list with all the news. There must be a header and then all the images related to that header :)

Comment: If you want them all in one row and can parse them out by a delimiter in your PHP, you can try using GROUP_CONCAT (see updated answer above).

Comment: Can you give an example how to parse them out by a delimiter via php?

Comment: Use the explode function with to split the comma-separated string into an array. You can then loop through that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159086/php-split-string