# Select text on a string after X symbol

Tags: php

i have this string

```
$string = "Social\Notify\Models\User";
```

How can i tell to php how select just the fourth segment of it? in this case just the word `User`?

Comment: See http://php.net/explode

Comment: I just up-voted you because i saw that someone down-voted you! Also gave you an example my friend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Split string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159086/php-split-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will do?

```
$str='Social\Notify\Models\User';
echo explode('\\',$str)[3]; //"prints" User
```

Comment: @ComFreek, Right. Modified it Thanks.

Comment: This symbol \ create conflict with the `'`

Comment: @Gilbert, Demo here https://eval.in/83990

Comment: Thank you! i'll wait 10 minutes for set this answer correct! Cheers!