# Split a string and access it

Tags: php, regex, string, split

```
friend_test2_2_Mobile
```

I have to split this `String` on the basis of `_` in `php` and acess data according to postions.

How do we split and access these in `php`

Please Help !!!

Comment: Did you make an attempt to solve it? What output do you expect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Split string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159086/php-split-string)

Comment: I didn't knew how to access these after the explode..!!

Comment: @user32876 It's an array. You can find ***billions*** of places explaining how to use an array in PHP.

Comment: As an aside, please read some of the PHP documentation. It's fairly clear and gives examples on how to use these functions. Also, Google is your friend. Just search for "php split string" and you'll get loads of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're looking for [`explode`](http://php.net/explode).

```
$parts = explode('_', 'friend_test2_2_mobile');
// $parts = array('friend','test2','2','mobile');
// $parts[0] = 'friend'
// $parts[1] = 'test2'
// $parts[2] = '2'
// $parts[3] = 'mobile'
```

Or if you want more control, you can use [`list`](http://php.net/list):

```
list($name,$foo,$id,$device) = explode('_', 'friend_test2_2_mobile')
// $name = 'friend'
// $foo = 'test2'
// $id = '2'
// $device = 'mobile'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`explode`](https://www.php.net/explode):

```
$data = explode('_', $string);
```

The results are an array, so you access the elements as you would any other array.

```
$friend = $data[0]
```

Comment: how do we access these ??