# Unexpected Regexp result with *

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to devise a regexp that extracts:

```
aa
bb
cc
```

from the subject:

```
aa,bb,cc
```

I'm using the following regexp:

```
|(.+?),*|
```

but the result is

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

Please help,

Thanks.

Comment: If it is a simple comma delimited list then why not use explode() i.e $result = explode(",",$text);

Comment: Because the actual subject is this a prolog-generated list like this: [1-[],2-[3-a,4-b,5-a,7-b,8-d,9-e,10-f,11-g,12-h,13-i,14-l,15-a,16-m],3-[]]

Comment: does the string must be repeated or can be alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Given your response (that doens't match your original question) - what exactly are you expecting back from the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` makes your match 'non-greedy', that means it will match the shortest possible string that satisfies the regular expression. Also, `,*` means `0 or more commas`.

What you're looking for is:

```
|[^,]+|
```

For example:

```php
<?php
$foo = "aa,bb,cc";
preg_match_all("/[^,]+/",$foo,$matches);
for($j=0;$j<count($matches[0]); $j++){
  print $matches[0][$j] .  "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the matched group from index 1.

```
(\w+),?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/7)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/(\\w+),?/m";
$str = "aa,bb,cc";
 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

---

You can use [PHP: Split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159086/php-split-string) as well using [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
```

Read more [How can I split a comma delimited string into an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/how-can-i-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Without any groups,

```
(?<=^|,)\w+
```

OR

```
\w+(?=,|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/9)

PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$data = "aa,bb,cc";
$regex =  '~(?<=^|,)\w+~';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "aa"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "bb"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "cc"
  }
}
```