# Get multiple substrings from a string in PHP

Tags: php

I want to extract multiple substrings from a string and put in an array..

for example:

```
$string = '{[John][16 years old][New York]}{[Michael][22 years old][Las Vegas]}{[Smith][32 years old][Chicago]}';
$array = ["John,16 years old, New York, Mihael, 22 years old, Las Vegas, Smith, 32 years old, Chicago"];
```

Someone any ideea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Split string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159086/php-split-string)

Comment: Is your example correct? The array has one single (string) element? If yes, the question really has nothing to do with arrays

Comment: your array consists in one only string element. It is what do you want?

Comment: ... or maybe you intend: [ 'John,16 years old,New York', 'Michael,22 years old,Las Vegas' ... ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will do it:

```
$string = '{[John][16 years old][New York]}{[Michael][22 years old][Las Vegas]}{[Smith][32 years old][Chicago]}';
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $string , $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($matches[1]);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => 16 years old
    [2] => New York
    [3] => Michael
    [4] => 22 years old
    [5] => Las Vegas
    [6] => Smith
    [7] => 32 years old
    [8] => Chicago
)
*/
```

**DEMO:**

http://ideone.com/ReaIOr

---

**UPDATE:**

To loop all matches you can use:

```
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    echo $matches[1][$i];
}
```

Comment: great. Thank you. Can you told me how can i get every element from array in a for? or, how can i print for example first element from array with the id = 0(John)

Comment: You can use a regular `for` to loop the matches. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be looking to create a single element array, containing a string with certain chars stripped. For this you can use `str_replace` and `trim`:

```
$string = '{[John][16 years old][New York]}{[Michael][22 years old][Las Vegas]}{[Smith][32 years old][Chicago]}';

$cleaned = trim(str_replace(['][', ']}{['],', ', $string), "{}[]");
$array = [$cleaned];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll be spoiled for choice!

This is another answer, if you want extract multiple substrings with name, age, city.

This is simple solution, using `substr`, `explode` and `str_replace`:

```
$array = array();
foreach( explode( ']}{[', substr( $string,2,-2 )) as $chunk )
{
    $array[] = str_replace( '][', ',', $chunk );
}
print_r( $array );
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/515257)**</kbd>

Obviously, it works only if there are not curly or squared brackets inside the sigle strings.

First of all, it remove from the original string opening and closing brackets, then `explode` (transform a string in array) the string by `][` and performs a `foreach` loop through obtained elements (`John][16 years old][New York` etc...); for each elements it replace every occurrence of `][` with `,` and append it to desired array.

That's all