# Split string programmatically php

Tags: php, split

I have this 2 strings:

String 1:

> AV. LOS TALLERES NRO. 4898 URB. EL NARANJAL LIMA - LIMA - INDEPENDENCIA

String 2:

> LA JOYA MZA. I LOTE. 13 -B (PLAZA PRINCIPAL DE LA JOYA)  AREQUIPA - AREQUIPA - LA JOYA

I want to output only from 1st string:

> LIMA - LIMA - INDEPENDENCIA

and from 2nd string:

> AREQUIPA - AREQUIPA - LA JOYA

I'm receiving those strings and I have to show only that part. There're always 3 parts and separated with `-` but the text changes, for example: what I receive could be one of:

> AREQUIPA - AREQUIPA - AREQUIPA
>
> LIMA - LIMA - ATE
>
> PROV. CONST. DEL CALLAO - PROV. CONST. DEL CALLAO - CALLAO
>
> AREQUIPA - CAMANA - CAMANA

How can I split them? I tried counting from the end to the last space after the `-`, but I feel there is a better way.

Comment: Is there only ever one word before the first `-`? Or can you have two words like in `LA JOYA`? Because that could make it quite complex.

Comment: It could be two words.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Maybe a [string function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) like [`strtok`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159086/php-split-string)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you:

1. We need to separate the strings with ' - ':

```
$string = "AV. LOS TALLERES NRO. 4898 URB. EL NARANJAL LIMA - LIMA - INDEPENDENCIA";
$farr = explode(' - ',$string);

=> [
     "AV. LOS TALLERES NRO. 4898 URB. EL NARANJAL LIMA",
     "LIMA",
     "INDEPENDENCIA",
   ]
```

2. Since you need the last part of the first portion on the string:

```
$sarr = explode(' ',$farr[0]);

=> [
     "AV.",
     "LOS",
     "TALLERES",
     "NRO.",
     "4898",
     "URB.",
     "EL",
     "NARANJAL",
     "LIMA",
   ]
```

3 print with:

```
echo end($sarr).' - '.$farr[1].' - '.$farr[2]
```

In the first, I'm using end to print only the last part of the second array. If you want to print more parts you'll need to change it

Comment: And what happend if i have "PROV. CONST. DEL CALLAO - PROV. CONST. DEL CALLAO - PROV. CONST. DEL CALLAO"?

Comment: @Oscar following my example it will print: **CALLAO - PROV. CONST. DEL CALLAO - PROV. CONST. DEL CALLAO**. My code will split the sting in three parts  by ' - ' then it will split the first position of the array by the ' ' and finally it will print the last position of the second split, the second position of the first split and the last position of the first split.

Answer (score -1):

*Current string -

```
$String1="AV. LOS TALLERES NRO. 4898 URB. EL NARANJAL LIMA - LIMA - INDEPENDENCIA";

$String2="LA JOYA MZA. I LOTE. 13 -B (PLAZA PRINCIPAL DE LA JOYA) AREQUIPA - AREQUIPA - LA JOYA";
```

*We need to split string to array

```
$arr1 = explode('-',$String1);

$arr2 = explode(') ',$String2);
```

*Create new string

```
$String1 = substr($arr1[0],-5).' - '.$arr1[1].' - '.$arr1[2];

$String2 = $arr2[1];
```

*Print final make new string

```
echo $String1; echo '<br>';

echo $String2;
```