# Get first number in array list

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I use laravel. And then when from submitted, it pass value as array.

My question is, how i can split the value? I want number before '-' and after '-'.

[image]

I want just like below:

[image]

and

[image]

My code just like below

```
   $form = $request->all();
   $emelto = $form['emelto'];
   $split = explode('-', $emelto );
```

but it shows error

```
explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

Please someone can help me.

Comment: You need to loop the `explode()` call on the `$emelto` arrray

Comment: Is it your fixed array input?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159086/php-split-string)

Comment: @fassn, i add foreach loop                                                                       
         foreach($emelto as $e)
        {
            $array1 = explode('-', $e[0] );
            dd($array1);
        }                                                                                                                              
       but it shows only first element.

Comment: @nice_dev.. the example only working if my $emelto only one value. But, my $emelto is an array collection value.

Comment: @Nurul fair enough, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Explode each individual string as you tried.
- Insert each number in it's respective column index in result.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$emelto = [
    '4-2',
    '11-5'
];

$data = [];
foreach($emelto as $str){
    foreach(explode('-',$str) as $index => $s){
        $data[$index] = $data[$index] ?? [];// assuming your PHP version supports ??
        $data[$index][] = $s;
    }
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();
foreach($request->emelto as $val){
    $dataArray = explode('-', $val);
    $array1[] = $dataArray[0];
    $array2[] = $dataArray[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**$emelto** is an array and you are passing it to explode. You have to pass it like **$emelto[0]**.

You should update your code with the below one.

```
<?php
$form = $request->all();
$emelto = $form['emelto'];
$array1 = explode('-', $emelto[0] );
$array2 = explode('-', $emelto[1] );

$array3 = array();
array_push($array3, $array1[0]);
array_push($array3, $array2[0]);

$array4 = array();
array_push($array4, $array1[1]);
array_push($array4, $array2[2]);
?>
```

Comment: Btw, thanks for the answer. But its not working. It gives me [4,2]. I want 1st number. [4,11]